# What is significance of ASHTAMI ?(waning Moon Ashtami)

Tags: shiva, krishna, time

If we look Kaal Bhairava,  avatar of Lord Shiva, Was first taken on Karthikai month waning Moon Ashtami. And Lord Krishna was born in Gokula Ashtami. What's the significance of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Tithi is dedicated to a particular deity. And, that deity basically indicates the significance of the Tithi.

The Tithis are also the days on which some of those deities had manifested for the 1st time.

For example, according to [Varaha Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookindex.php), Pratipad Tithi belongs to Agni. This day should be dedicated to appeasing Agni. Similarly, Dwitiya Tithi is dedicated to the Aswini Kuamars and so on.

In this manner Chaturthis are dedicated to Ganesha, Panchamis to Nagas (snakes), Shashtis to Karthikeya etc.

In this list the Ashtami Tithis are dedicated to [the Ashta Matrikas](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=15).

> The entire Universe was upset by the wickedness and glaring
>   transgression of morals by the uninterrupted evils displayed by Demon
>   Andhakasura [Siva Purana states that Devi Parvati was playful with
>   Maha Deva by closing His eyes tightly and from the Lord�s perspiration
>   on His forehead a boy of muscular strength was created.]Eventually
>   Andhakasura became the Unconquered King of the Lower Regions like
>   Patala and tormented the entire Universe. After a series of battles
>   were won with Devas who were driven away from the Heaven, Indra
>   approached Brahma and Vishnu who too were ineffective to conquer the
>   Demon as he was fortified with the boons of Brahma. They had finally
>   approached Maha Deva and to His utter surprise He too could not
>   conquer him as each time Maha Deva applied His trident against the
>   Demon, blood streams of the Demon�s body created endless number of
>   Andhakasuras with each drop of his blood. Lord Rudra became so
>   infuriated that from His face produced a mighty conflagration or an
>   inferno-like flame viz. the Yogishwari Shakti. Vishnu too created a
>   highly powerful Shakti named Devi Vaishnavi and other Deities followed
>   suit by creating their Shakti counter-parts viz. Brahmi from Brahma,
>   Kaumari from Kartikeya, Mahendri from Indra, Yami or Poushunyam from
>   Yama, Varahi from Varaha Deva and Maheswari from Narayana. The Eight
>   Matrikas represented the Eight Mind born Enemies viz. Kama or Desire
>   from Yogeswari, Krodha or fury from Maheswari, lobha or avarice from
>   Vaishnavi, Mada or Ego from Brahmani, Moha or infatuation from
>   Kaumari, Poushunya or wickedness from Yamadharani, Matsarya from
>   Indrani and Jealousy from Varahi. The blood streams from Andhaka�s
>   body got dried up by the Matrikas; the Rakshasa Maya or the illusion
>   created by the Demon was terminated and Andhaka too got exterminated.
>   **The combined strength of Marikas is an extraordinary might of Eight Shaktis providing security and propitiousness to devotees and Lord
>   Brahma declared Ashtami Thithi in the Monthly Calendar. Those who
>   observe this particular day with fast by eating Bel patra with
>   devotion are blessed with excellent health, well being and
>   contentment.**

However, according to astrology, each of these Tithis have an over ruling Graha.

For example, 1st Tithi (Pratpiada) is ruled by Sun, 2nd Tithi by Moon, 3rd by Mars, 4th by Mercury, 5th by Jupiter, 6th by Venus, 7th by Saturn and 8th by Rahu and this is the order for the remaining Tithis as well. So, 9th again is ruled by Sun, 10th by Moon etc.

The complete list is given [here.](https://shrifreedom.org/vedic-astrology/tithi/)

So, Ashtami Tithi is ruled by Rahu too.

Comment: What does Tantra say about this?

Comment: Well nothing specific.. Ashtami is one of the special days for Devi worship.. Ashtami is also one of the Ashtakas.. @AkshayKumarS Also in Sri Vidya the day is ruled by Devi's one specific form.